# Unity3D - Audio playing getting muted after getting any call/notification on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio, phone-call

I have audio playing issue on Android build. I'm using Unity 5.4.0b15, but I had same issue on 5.3.4p3.

I have simple component for playing background music added to "AudioPlayer" GameObject in my scene.

```
public AudioClip clip;
private AudioSource _musicAudioSource;

private void Awake()
{
   if (_musicAudioSource == null)
   {
       _musicAudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
   }
   _musicAudioSource.loop = true;
   _musicAudioSource.clip = clip;
   _musicAudioSource.Play();
}
```

After running game on Android devices the music starts playing perfectly. But while it running I'm getting any kind of notification or call (phone, viber or any other massinger) the music stops playing. Also all the other sounds playing getting muted, which I used in gameplay. The only way to restart playing audio is to kill application and run it again.

Also getting same muted issue, when I'm running game while listening any audio using native player, like Play Music.

On iOS everything works perfectly.

Comment: You accepted my answer so I thought it worked for you. Please don't accept answers unless they solved your problem. Just for a quick notice, this has been solved in 5.4.0B23  today. http://unity3d.com/unity/beta

Comment: any workaround for this??? I am having the same issue in 5.3.5f1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in Unity. I bumped into the same problem and ran some tests to try to fix it but there is no way to recover the audio without restarting the app.

In my tests I used Google Hangouts notifications to kill the audio.

Programmer's proposed fix won't work because:
1. The notification does not trigger application pause nor application focus events.
2. Initializing a new AudioListener and/or AudioSource instances will not recover the audio either.

This is a low level bug in Unity. I will make a report on the bug.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thanks a lot for your answer. I still have same issue and agree with you about low level bug in Unity. I also find bug in Unity Issue Tracker.
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-slash-audio-android-app-stops-playing-audio-at-all-if-another-app-takes-audio-focus

Answer (score 2):

> On iOS everything works perfectly.

`Android != iOS`.

Use `OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)` to detect when the Application is paused and resumed. The `pauseStatus` variable will return `true` when the app is **paused**, and `false` when the app is **resumed**. So, manually pause the the music when `pauseStatus` is `true` and resume the music when `pauseStatus` is `false`.

```
public AudioClip clip;
private AudioSource _musicAudioSource;
bool _musicAudioSourcePaused = false;

void Awake()
{
    if (_musicAudioSource == null)
    {
        _musicAudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        _musicAudioSource.loop = true;
        _musicAudioSource.clip = clip;
    }

    //Check if Audio is playing. Don't play if already playing. 
    if (!_musicAudioSource.isPlaying)
    {
        _musicAudioSource.Play();
    }
}

void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    //Check if this is Pause
    if (pauseStatus)
    {
        //Pause Audio if it is playing
        if (_musicAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            _musicAudioSource.Pause();

            //Set to true so that we will detamine whether to Play() or UnPause() the music next time
            _musicAudioSourcePaused = true;
        }
    }

    //Check if this is Resume
    if (!pauseStatus)
    {
        //Make sure audio is not null. If null, getComponent again
        if (_musicAudioSource == null)
        {
            _musicAudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            _musicAudioSource.loop = true;
            _musicAudioSource.clip = clip;
        }

        //Check if we paused the audio then resume
        if (_musicAudioSourcePaused)
        {
            _musicAudioSource.UnPause();

            //Set to false so that we will detamine whether to Play() or UnPause() the music next time
            _musicAudioSourcePaused = false;
        }

        //Check if Audio is playing. Don't play if already playing. 
        if (!_musicAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            _musicAudioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```